# Using Residue Theorem to evaluate Trigonometric Integral $I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{F(x)}{a^2+b^2(\cos x-\cos y)^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{F(x)}{a^2+b^2(\cos x-\cos y)^2}dx ,\quad 0<y<\pi,$$

in the regime $a\ll b$, using Residue Theorem. I'm assuming that $F(x)$ is a well-behaved function with no singularities in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. I've tried the standard approach by defining $z=e^{ix}$ and $z_0=e^{iy}$ to convert the integral into the form

$$I=-\frac{2i}{\pi}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z_0^2\,z\,F[-i \log (z)]}{4 a^2 \,z_0^2\,z^2+b^2 (z_0-z)^2 (z_0\,z-1)^2}dz.$$

In the regime considered, the first term in the denominator of the above expression can be neglected. The poles will be then $z=z_0$ and $z=\frac{1}{z_0}$, both of them with multiplicity 2.

And here's my problem: both singularities relies on the unity circle $|z|=1.$ How can I proceed from here or what should be the best approach to deal with this integral? I was expecting to be able to find an answer that depends on $F(y)$ or $F^\prime(y)$. But that's only a guess.

This is my very first question in stackexchange. I hope I had followed all the instructions properly.

Comment: The only thing which I suggest is, if possible, to include the integral in the title of the question. The aim is to make question titles as descriptive as possible: there are many questions about *'using the residue theorem to evaluate trigonometric integrals'*.

Comment: The contour in the mapping $e^{ix}\to z$ is the upper-half unit circle only.  So, the residue theorem will not be of much use in that case.  If $F$ were an even function, then the integrand is also even and $I$ is $1/2$ of the integral over $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for your observation @MarkViola. In fact I assumed F was an even function when I converted the integral to the second form.

Comment: @projectilemotion, I've added the integral in the title of the question. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome.  There is another issue.  The numerator term $F(-i\log(z))$ embeds the complex logarithm, which contains a branch point at $z=0$.  Therefore, this renders the residue theorem inapplicable here.